# How can I change the values of different columns of a csv - file without losing the structur?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, calculation

I want to change the values of some columns of a csv - file.

This is my csv - file:

**1_stride.csv**

```
,euler x,euler y,euler z,accel x,accel y,accel z,force heel,force metatarsus,force toe
830,202.12,20.880000000000013,-38.39,0.11,-1.41,-0.04,3.0,5.666666666666667,6.666666666666667
831,202.06,21.000000000000018,-38.010000000000005,0.14,-1.32,-0.05,2.75,5.666666666666667,6.666666666666667
832,202.06,21.000000000000018,-38.010000000000005,0.22,-1.21,-0.14,2.75,5.666666666666667,7.0
833,202.0,21.320000000000014,-37.45,0.23,-1.13,-0.18,2.75,6.0,7.333333333333333
834,202.0,21.320000000000014,-37.45,0.23,-1.13,-0.18,2.25,6.333333333333333,7.0
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...
```

Now I want to multiply the columns "accel x", "accel y" and "euler y" by -1.
How can I reach this, that I get a new csv - file in the end like this **1_stride_new.csv**:

```
,euler x,euler y,euler z,accel x,accel y,accel z,force heel,force metatarsus,force toe
830,202.12,-20.880000000000013,-38.39,-0.11,1.41,-0.04,3.0,5.666666666666667,6.666666666666667
831,202.06,21.000000000000018,-38.010000000000005,-0.14,1.32,-0.05,2.75,5.666666666666667,6.666666666666667
832,202.06,-21.000000000000018,-38.010000000000005,-0.22,1.21,-0.14,2.75,5.666666666666667,7.0
833,202.0,-21.320000000000014,-37.45,-0.23,1.13,-0.18,2.75,6.0,7.333333333333333
834,202.0,-21.320000000000014,-37.45,-0.23,1.13,-0.18,2.25,6.333333333333333,7.0
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...
```

I have already tried it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"1_stride.csv")
((daten['accel x'])*(-1)).to_csv(r"1_Stride _new.csv", index=False, line_terminator = ',\n')
```

But then I get the following new csv - file:

```
-0.11,
-0.14,
-0.22,
-0.23,
-0.23,
.....,
```

Unfortunately, however, this is not the output I would like to have. The other columns and also the labels in the "Table header" are missing.
I do not know how to make it so that I get such an output as I have already shown how it should be (see above at **1_stride_new.csv**).

Thanks for helping me!

**EDIT**

I did it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv(r"1_Stride.csv")

data[["accel x","accel y","euler y"]] = data[["accel x","accel y","euler y"]].mul(-1)
data.to_csv(r"1_Stride_new.csv")
```

But then I get an output of the new csv - file like this:

```
,Unnamed: 0,euler x,euler y,euler z,accel x,accel y,accel z,force heel,force metatarsus,force toe
0,830,202.12,-20.880000000000013,-38.39,-0.11,1.41,-0.04,3.0,5.666666666666668,6.666666666666668
1,831,202.06,-21.000000000000018,-38.01000000000001,-0.14,1.32,-0.05,2.75,5.666666666666668,6.666666666666668
2,832,202.06,-21.000000000000018,-38.01000000000001,-0.22,1.21,-0.14,2.75,5.666666666666668,7.0
3,833,202.0,-21.32000000000001,-37.45,-0.23,1.13,-0.18,2.75,6.0,7.333333333333332
4,834,202.0,-21.32000000000001,-37.45,-0.23,1.13,-0.18,2.25,6.333333333333332,7.0
5,835,201.94,-21.440000000000012,-37.2,-0.2,1.03,-0.19,2.5,6.333333333333332,7.333333333333332

...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...
```

Something has gone wrong. Could someone tell me how I can fix this (the first column must be gone or should not look like this)? The new csv - file should look the same as the first one, but with the changed values.

Comment: Do: `data[['"accel x","accel y","euler y"]] = data[['"accel x","accel y","euler y"]].mul(-1)`

Comment: You are creating a csv file from `data['accel x']` and not `data`. I guess this is where you lose your other columns. Doing what Mayank Porwal proposes should update your table, then you can simply call `data.to_csv(...)` to save it.

Comment: @Mayank Porwal After doing this, I get a new DataFrame with 3 columns. But no CSV file with these new values and columns. This is difficult.

Comment: Ah ok. Now I understand it. Thank you @SpaceBurger 
Now it works. Thanks

Comment: Could you check out the edit in my question, please? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't pass the argument `index=False` when calling `to_csv`. The index is added as the first column to the new csv.